# PDB - pop up console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

I have some python code which is being run by a web service when a button is clicked. This means that I don't have a console associated with the python process.

Is it possible to "pop up" a PDB debugger, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **web pdb** module of python. It is very useful when you do web oriented testing where you might not be running in a console.

[web pdb](https://pypi.org/project/web-pdb/)